# How to change line color with VBA

Tags: colors, line, powerpoint, shapes

What if I need to change the color for only some of the lines in powerpoint? How do I get an index or ID for each line?

Comment: Iterate through the shapes collection. Each shape has both an .Index and an .ID property. The .Index represents the shape's position in the "stacking order" on the slide. Shapes with a higher index will cover up shapes with a lower index when they overlap.  The index will change when the order is changed or when shapes are deleted. The .ID property is assigned to a shape when it's created and will not change.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Hi, thanks, ... are considered noise](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950);